# Intl.DateTimeFormat() doesn't reflect given locale when code is run by GitHub workflow

Tags: javascript, github, pipeline

I have a GitHub workflow configured to run my tests.

Part of my code is a date formatting with `Intl` with this simple configuration and usage (simplified for this question):

```js
const dateFormatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('cs-CZ');
console.log(dateFormatter.format(new Date('2020-01-01')));
```

On my localhost, the test result is correct as expected. However, when running the test by GitHub workflow, the result is different.

```js
// localhost
console.log(dateFormatter.format(new Date('2020-01-01'))); // 1. 1. 2020 

// GitHub
console.log(dateFormatter.format(new Date('2020-01-01'))); // 1/1/2020
```

Is any other configuration for `Intl` required or is it some bug?

GitHub workflow Node.js version: 12.x, local Node.js version 12.12.0. Locale on my local dev computer is en-US.

Comment: can be probably connected to node settings on GitHub https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/intl.html